# Is there a command to show aggregate/merge results of all systemd conf.d drop-in files?

Tags: systemd

I think I have basically understood how those [`systemd drop-in files`](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/etc-configuration-directories) work, like `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` or `/etc/sudoers.d/`

**My question: is there some helper command to show the current aggregate result?**

i.e. seeing how everything plays together in the `.d` Folder and verifying i.e. that `fooProperty` is finally `true` not `false`…

Answer (score 2):

For service units you list all the properties with `systemctl show` or use option `-p` or `--property` to list just one. You can also use `systemctl cat` to concatenate all the various files, though without any merging of the information. Eg, for my `http.service`:

```
$ systemctl cat httpd 
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service     <--highlighted
....
[Unit]
Description=The Apache HTTP Server
...
[Service]
...
PrivateTmp=true
...

# /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/override.conf  <--highlighted
[Service]
PrivateTmp=false
UMask=0002
```

The above shows by a comment (highlighted in a terminal) the name of each of 2 files followed by its contents. You can see how the `override.conf` file provides a different value for `PrivateTmp`.  You can see the resulting value with

```
$ systemctl show  --property=PrivateTmp httpd
PrivateTmp=no
```

However, this doesn't work with other units, like `httpd.socket`, which you can `show` as above, but which fails on a property in the files that I overrode:

```
$ systemctl show  --property=ListenStream httpd.socket
Property ListenStream does not exist.
```

I'm using version 231, things may have changed.

Comment: Great approach. I am `aiming` at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d`. For which I get the “does not exist” as you describe. I was now hoping to find it in ` systemctl list-units | grep -i ssh`, but no luck…

Comment: I imagine that systemd has just borrowed the include file convention and extended it with utilities for its own purposes. I don't know of any pre-existing tools to do the same thing with the old adhoc use done by ssh etc. You'll just have to write your own awk script!